# Creating Pyramid/SQLAlchemy models from MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I would like to use Pyramid and SQLAlchemy with an already existing MySQL database.
Is it possible to automatically create the models from the MySQL tables. I do not want to write them all by hand.
This could be either by retrieving the tables and structure from the Server or using a MySQL "Create Table..." script, which contains all the tables.

Thanks in advance,
Linus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLAlchemy you can reflect your database like this:

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData

    engine = create_engine(uri)
    meta = MetaData(bind=engine)
    meta.reflect()
```

Then, meta.tables are your tables.
By the way, it is described here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html

To generate the code based on the database tables there are packages such as https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlacodegen and http://turbogears.org/2.0/docs/main/Utilities/sqlautocode.html , but I haven't used them.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
One more question. How do i get from the table object to plain code. So i do not have to reflect my db every single time and work on it in my project?

Comment: Merci i'll have a look